# I'm trying to read from a text file and categorize them into different members of structure but i don't know where it went wrong

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct
{
    int isbn_code, year_published, quantity, rack, level_no;
    char author[50], title[100], publisher[50];
    double price;
}DATA;
```

Shown above is my typedef struct.
And when i debug, it only shows "1. ".
So here is my code.
Please tell me what's wrong and what do i need to do to make it execute properly.
I'm just trying to read from a text file and categorize them into different members of structure.

```
int file_reader()
{
    DATA d;
    ifstream infile("books.txt", ios::in);
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < 100; row++)
            {
                cout << row << ". ";
                char line[200];
                cin.ignore();
                cin.getline(line, 200, '\n');

                char* column = strtok(line, ",");

                while(column)
                {
                    cin >> d.isbn_code;
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin.getline(column, 50);
                    strcpy(d.author,column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin.getline(column, 100);
                    strcpy(d.title, column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin.getline(column, 50);
                    strcpy(d.publisher, column);
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin >> d.year_published;
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin >> d.quantity;
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin >> d.price;
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin >> d.rack;
                    column = strtok(NULL, ",");
                    cin >> d.level_no;
                }
                cout << d.isbn_code << "," << d.author << "," << d.title << "," << d.publisher << "," 
                    << d.year_published << "," << d.quantity << "," << d.price << "," << d.rack << "," << d.level_no;
            } cout << endl;
        } infile.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "File is not open\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem (well, maybe a little related) but I think you need to invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).  I also recommend you learn about [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and try it out on the piece of code you show.

Comment: @john I think they did say it only prints "1." but then again they said "when I debug" so \*shrug\*

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong

```
cin >> d.isbn_code;
```

That reads the ISBN code from `cin` not from your file. Probably what you intended is this

```
d.isbn_code = atoi(column);
```

Then on the next three lines

```
column = strtok(NULL, ",");
cin.getline(column, 50);
strcpy(d.author,column);
```

Again you are reading from `cin` not from your file. I think that you meant this

```
column = strtok(NULL, ",");
strcpy(d.author,column);
```

Basically you are making the same mistake over and over, you are reading from `cin` when you said you wanted to read from a file. That's why your program isn't doing anything, it's waiting for you to type something.

There's other problems as well (your loops are all wrong, you only have one DATA struct when clearly you want many, for example). But fix the input first and then have another look.

Comment: @YingShuang If you have any more problems you should make a new question